Streaming an Updating Folder of Images with FFmpeg Without Restarting the Script
I'm working on a project where I need to stream a series of images stored in a folder using FFmpeg.
My current command looks like this:
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -f image2 -framerate 5 -i "C:\Images\%d.bmp" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 35 -pix_fmt bgra -vf format=bgra -f mpegts "udp://127.0.0.1:8554?pkt_size=1316&buffer_size=64k"

Initially, the folder contains:
Input:
1.bmp
2.bmp
3.bmp
.
.
.
N.bmp

Running this command successfully streams the images. However, new images (e.g., N2.bmp) might be added to the folder during runtime, and I need these new images to be included in the stream without restarting FFmpeg.
Challenges:

I need to include newly added images in the ongoing stream without rerunning the FFmpeg command.
I delete the .bmp files after they are streamed to avoid filling up my hard disk, so rerunning the command is not an option.

Additional Context:
The FFmpeg command is embedded within my .NET program, which handles the deletion of images after they are streamed. This ensures that my PC's hard disk does not fill up, but it also means I cannot simply restart the FFmpeg command whenever new images are added.
Question:
Is there a way to configure FFmpeg or use an additional tool to dynamically update the input source to include newly added images without stopping and restarting the FFmpeg command?
Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

For me my result was to implement NamedPipeServerStream and use it as my input using the following command:
 ffmpeg -f image2pipe -re -framerate 5 -i \\.\pipe\imagePipe -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 35 -pix_fmt yuv444p -f mpegts "udp://127.0.0.1:8554?pkt_size=1316&buffer_size=64k"

And after an image was converted into byte[] and flushed down the pipe, I've deleted it.

Instead of writing new files in the Images folder, you can re-write a single file and use that as an input. To make it work you'll have to use an additional readrate option or simply re option for real-time speed i.e. tell ffmpeg to read 1s of input in 1s of wallclock time.
Your updated command will look like below:
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -f image2 -framerate 5 -i "C:\Images\image.bmp" -c:v libx264 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced)" -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 35 -f mpegts "udp://127.0.0.1:8554?pkt_size=1316&buffer_size=64k"
You can then replace your image.bmp file whenever it becomes available from within your .NET program.
Note:

libx264 does not support bgra pixel format. If you still put these in your command, ffmpeg automatically uses it's preferred format for libx264. Hence in my suggested command I have removed these.
It is recommended to set keyframe interval to avoid any potential decoding issues in the downstream process that will be ingressing your UDP stream. In my suggested example, this has been set to 1s by using force_key_frames option.


By my logic, if no new images appear, it will keep stream the last image constantly, and thus "C:\Images\image.bmp" will never be available to write.
I think my solution is to implement a pipeline that will act as my "dynamic input", I will check it and will post if it does work.

If I understand you correctly, you want to continue displaying the last image in case a new image does not arrive, right? In that case, this will work as expected. Of course, this command expects some starting image to be present at the path "C:\Images\image.bmp" to start. In case you want to start this command before your .net program can start sending actual images, you can always keep some reference image on this path. For example an image with just black/white color. The command then will start successfully and the output will change when your program starts sending actual images.
